# Sort using jquery datas come from Mysql query PHP

Tags: jquery, sorting, html

I want to know how I can sort these div according to the year with Jquery or AJAX(I'm newbie),I have this schema :

```
  <div class="content">
       <h1 class="year"><a name='2012'>2012</a></h1>
           <ul>
              <li>

              </li>

          </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
       <h1 class="year"><a name='2011'>2011</a></h1>
            <ul>

             <li>

             </li>
           </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="content">
      <h1 class="year"><a name='2010'>2010</a></h1>
            <ul>
             <li>

            </li>

           </ul>
 </div>
```

I want to sort in order to obtain :

```
    <div class="content">
           <h1 class="year"><a name='2010'>2010</a></h1>...............
     <div class="content">
          <h1 class="year"><a name='2011'>2011</a></h1>................
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found with JQuery:

```
$('div.content').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);
});
```